# Find visually similar images for a given image file (on Windows)

Tags: windows, images, search, computer-vision

I want a software for Windows to find visually similar images (pictures) on my hard disk. My need is it must find a given image is visually similar.

That is, take a sample image as input and search throughout the computer and find any images visually similar to it.

I have tried many visually similarity image finders, but they all are only cross-checking each and every file against each other to find all possible combinations of similar images. None offers it for a single image specified, as I need it.

See [Find visually similar images to a given image](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17429/find-visually-similar-images-to-a-given-image) for Linux software.

Answer (score 6):

Just found this today on my search for something similar.
(I've been looking for this for years usually once a year. happened to be today)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/imgseek/

> imgSeek is a photo collection manager and viewer with content-based
>   search and many other features. The query is expressed either as a
>   rough sketch painted by the user or as another image you supply (or an
>   image in your collection).

[image]

Comment: Wow! That looks very impressive! Upvote from me - welcome aboard, Jeremy :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try [search by image](https://vitali-fedulov.github.io/similar.pictures/similar-image-search.html) browser-based OS-independent tool (Windows, Linux, Mac etc.), which I developed.

If you have a good PC, it is possible to scan more than 100000 images without a problem.

In case of privacy concerns, it is possible to save and host the tool page locally (e.g. on http://localhost:8000/ with a [local Python server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977972/how-do-i-setup-a-local-http-server-using-python)). This way no information will pass to the Internet at all.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul There is no download or extension: it is a web application, so it works directly in the browser. It appears to be free to use, but the website doesn't seem to have any privacy policy, despite it claiming to collect usage data. Perhaps @ Similar.Pictures can help?

Comment: @Charlie Harding: Thanks for voicing your concern about the privacy. To my best knowledge there is no need for the privacy policy statement, since no personal data (PII) is collected (as stated in the Terms of Service for each of the tools).

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks! I tried this on a small folder with Wifi disconnected and it works nicely. Next test is to try find an image in a much larger selection of files.

Do you know if the algorithm works if the source image is a square but the original photo to find is in a different aspect ratio? Thanks

Comment: @Nick Middleweek: In relation to the aspect ratio, the algorithm tolerates 10% difference of width or height between the matches. Else it considers images different. But it is possible to modify the threshold manually by changing a JavaScript constant in Developer Tools (it has value 10). The images will not match if the square is a considerable crop from the original. If my answer is not what you need, please share the image pair example, so I can look at it.

Answer (score 4):

The best Windows tool I can find for this is Visipics http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page

It basically uses ImageMagick to fingerprint images, with a slider to pick out the similarity values.

However, it seems to only do bulk comparisons (so you can't specify one file to look for, only whole folders).

Comment: but can't you have a folder with only one image in it?

Comment: The problem is identifying filenames etc is not as straightforward, but it is possible. You tend to have to tell it to pick files from within a given foder and subfolders, and then specifically mark which ones to keep etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've developed a software product which is currently in Beta, and it is currently free. You choose folder sets (the root folder of a set of folders, or on its own) and the software will find similar images across the sets, as long as they are very similar (almost the same image). The only thing is that it takes time the first time to analyze all your images (1hr for 15,000 images the first time only, on my PC). Give it a try and if you'd like, make a suggestion and I will try to accomodate your request in a future release. The web-site is [HomeMediaTools.com](https://www.homemediatools.com). Please do report any issues and give me feedback on your experience. It's always appreciated.